# Android error for double

Tags: android, function, compiler-errors

I am new to android and I have a problem.

I want to calculate BMR in android and I have some errors. Can you help me out?`public class BMRF extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public double calculareBMR(double i, double g, double v){
    double rezultat;
    rezultat = 665.09 + (9.56*g) + (1.84 * i) - (4.67 * v);
    return rezultat;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmrf);

    EditText inalt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText greut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText varst = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    double inaltime = Double.parseDouble(inalt.getText().toString());
    double greutate = Double.parseDouble(greut.getText().toString());
    double varsta = Double.parseDouble(varst.getText().toString());

    double rezultat = calculareBMR(inaltime,greutate,varsta);

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BMRF.this);
    builder.setTitle("Calorii necesare");
    builder.setMessage("Trebuie consumate urmatoarele calorii" + rezultat);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setNeutralButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    Button despre=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    despre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
    });

}
```

}
`

Stacktrace:

[image]

Comment: "I have some errors" -  which errors ? triggered by which line ? what's the input ?

Comment: Sorry, i have uploaded an image with the errors.i forgot to set the descriprion for the image. "enter image description here"

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you're trying to parse an empty string as a number, probably triggered by one of the lines that have `Double.parseDouble(...` you should either provide a default value or make validations on the input before you parse it.

Comment: thanks. It is working now